# Load const namespace variables values from file

Tags: c++, file, namespaces, constants, sfml

I have the following code:

colors.hpp:

```
#ifndef COLORS_HPP
#define COLORS_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics/Color.hpp>

namespace Colors
{
    extern const sf::Color Global;
    extern const sf::Colot Text;
}

#endif // COLORS_HPP
```

colors.cpp:

```
#include "colors.hpp"

namespace Colors
{
    const sf::Color Global(50, 50, 50, 255);
    const sf::Color Text(255, 255, 255, 255);
}
```

And so I wanted to know if there was a way to load the values for those variables from a file on the computer, like for example "colors.txt". I know I could use a class, but I want these variables to be accessible in the whole program by just including "colors.hpp".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this

```
#include "colors.hpp"

sf::Color loadFromFile(std::string const& filename) {
   sf::Color result;
   // open file 'filename'
   // update result
   return result;
}

namespace Colors
{
    const sf::Color Global{loadFromFile("file1")};
    const sf::Color Text{loadFromFile("file2")};
}
```

Comment: Of course, this doesn't let you portably get and use filenames from the command line.

Comment: This also  invites static initialization fiascoes , having substantial code running perhaps before `main`... and what if reading the file fails?

Comment: @aschepler Yes, passing files from command line would be a challenge.

Comment: @M.M There are no dependencies among the initializations, so I don't expect a static initialization fiasco. But since you brought it up, it may be worth changing `std::string` to `char const*`. The error handling strategy can be the same as otherwise, few possibilities are: (a) exit, (b) log and return default values (of `sf::Color`).